# How can I check if my variable is equal to NULL ? C

Tags: c, null-check

I have to write code which will be checking if input in my code is correct. I have to prevent entering letters, NULLs etc.

I tried simple if(*tab == NULL)..  but I can't compare float and void values.

```
int avg(const float* tab, unsigned int size, float *result)
{
    if( size <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    float suma = 0;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        suma=suma + *(tab+i);
    }
    *result = suma / size;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is not like JavaScript or SQL: value types cannot be `NULL` because they aren't pointers. `NULL` is just a constant value equal to zero (in most compilers). Pointers are just (special) integer numbers.

Comment: This question is literally like asking how to compare apples to oranges.

Comment: If you want to make sure that the caller is not passing a null pointer, just compare the pointer to `NULL` as in `tab == NULL` (or `tab != NULL`). If you use `*tab` then you dereference the pointer which will not work well if it's a null pointer.

Comment: Regarding pointers and dereferencing, note that the expression `*(tab+i)` is *exactly* equal to `tab[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand (and less to write).

Comment: So what can I do if checking machine types "int res = avg(NULL, 13, &result);" ??? I know this question is stupid, but I have no idea have to prevent entering NULL.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot use table reference by []

Comment: You can't prevent a caller of your function from passing any weird arguments to your function. What you can do is do some validation (like `if (tab == NULL) return 1;` or the size check you already do. If the user is passing a non-null pointer, then it's the fault of the caller and not you if it's not a valid pointer.

Comment: Note that `if (*tab != NULL)` is the same as `if (*(tab + 0) != NULL)`. In other words, just as `*(tab+i)` is the entry in the table at index `i`, `*tab` is the entry in the table at index 0. The entry at index 0 is a `float`, and `NULL` is typically the value 0 cast to a `void *`. Hence the compiler warning that you're comparing a `float` to a `void *`.

Comment: BTW, when asking a question about a compiler warning, be sure to follow these three simple steps. 1) Post the exact code that generates the warning. 2) Post the exact text of the warning. 3) Add a comment to the code that indicates the line where the warning occurred.

Comment: I think this question should be upvoted. Sure, it's a very beginnerish mistake, but I can imagine more people wondering about this.

Answer (score 2):

C does not store values the same way as Javascript or Python. In C, there's no such thing as a variable without value. You can never determine if a variable is initialized or not only by looking at the variable itself. A variable can be uninitialized, but using the variable then would lead to *undefined behavior* and the most likely consequence of ub in this case is that you get a random value that has a high probability of being zero.

If you do the declaration `float f`, then you reserve a certain amount of memory (usually 4 bytes for a float). Each time you use `f` in an expression, then whatever bit pattern that is found at the address `&f` will be interpreted as a float. Some bit patterns may be special for floats but NULL is not one of them, but when it comes to integers, then EVERY bit pattern is a valid regular integer.

You simply have to make sure that `tab` is properly initialized *before* passing it to your function. The function itself cannot determine if that's the case.

In C, NULL is a constant, usually of type `void*`, but it may also be of type `int`. The intended purpose is for pointers and should not be used for anything else.

Furthermore, C is a statically typed language, which means that a variable can never change type. A float can never contain letters. You can, via *casting*, make a float to contain the same bit pattern as an integer, a four character string, a pointer or something else, but most likely the result would not make sense.

Comment: I would contest the "strongly typed" since you can reinterpret/cast any data in C to whatever type you like and neither the compiler nor the executing machine will stop you (well, until something breaks). Unlike in most higher-level languages like Python, Java, Smalltalk etc. where you cannot pretend that one object is of a different type than it actually is. I would therefore write "statically typed" instead. The distinction is hardly relevant for the question though.